# Change Ubuntu Top bar Icon

Tags: icons

I need to change top bar setting icon to Ubuntu logo icon. I searched on following location

```
/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-dark/ 
/usr/share/unity/themes/ 
/usr/share/unity/icons/
```

and I can't find that icon. I don't use any icon set rather than Ubuntu defaults, can anyone help me that would be a great favor.

Please refer this image:

[image]

Comment: Those are located in /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/22
and that one to be exact is system-devices-panel.svg

Comment: shall I put that in an answer then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files you seek are found in  `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-light/status/22`
and that one to be exact is `system-devices-panel.svg`

Ubuntu uses two icon themes one for light, being `ubuntu-mono-light` and one for dark, being `ubuntu-mono-dark`

The additional icons can be found in folders called `hicolor` and `gnome` which are located in `/usr/share/icons`